# Исправить горизонтальное растяжение названия столбца в таблице QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt6

Подскажите пожалуйста, как увеличить в *PyQt6*  горизонтальное название столбца, как из **`End Nodes`** сделать как **`Common Nodes`**.

```
    self.grid_layout2 = QGridLayout()            
    self.table2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)   
    self.table2.setColumnCount(1)            
    self.table2.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["End Nodes"])
    self.table2.setStyleSheet('background : #afcde7; font-weight: 500; color: #414244;')
    Getfnt2 = self.table2.font()
    Getfnt2.setPointSize(9)
    self.table2.setFont(Getfnt2)
    self.table2.setGeometry(285, 55, 255, 270)
    self.grid_layout2.addWidget(self.table2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пожалуйста, объясните лучше (на русском языке) что вы хотите сделать и добавьте [mcve] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> stretchLastSection : bool
>
> Это свойство указывает, занимает ли последний видимый раздел в заголовке все доступное пространство.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        
        self.table2 = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(1, 1)   
#        self.table2.setColumnCount(1)            
        self.table2.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["End Nodes"])
        
        self.table2.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)     # +++

        self.table2.setStyleSheet('''
            background : #afcde7; 
            font-weight: 500; 
            color: #414244;
        ''')

        Getfnt2 = self.table2.font()
        Getfnt2.setPointSize(9)
        self.table2.setFont(Getfnt2)
#        self.table2.setGeometry(285, 55, 255, 270)
        
        self.grid_layout2 = QGridLayout(self)            
        self.grid_layout2.addWidget(self.table2) 
        
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сработало!